# Masonry effect without a delay when resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-float, jquery-masonry

**TL;DR:** See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UTB5C/) - pretty much all I'm looking for is a JavaScript doohickey that would fix the gaps between floated elements such as these, without the delay when resizing that existing libraries have.

**Longer version:** So as I understand it, there are two major libraries for creating walls of tightly-knit elements; [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) and [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/).

However, apart from the suspiciously similar websites, both these libraries have the same oddity when it comes to resizing the viewport with fluid/responsive elements. Each masonry'd element first resizes individually (creating larger gutters), and then a beat later, gets re-arranged to the new form. See it [here](http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/fluid.html) or [here](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/fluid-responsive.html).

It seems I'm the only one who thinks this is ugly.

How can I achieve the same masonry effect, but with more 'native' looking resizing (i.e. one without the delay), considering an element width set in percentages, and gutters?

Here's the CSS I have now:

```css
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#wrapper > div {
    width: 46%;
    margin: 0 2% 15px;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: I'm not as familiar with Isotope, but the Masonry code uses a throttled event handler on the window's `resize` event to trigger a recalculation of the bricks position in the wall. The behaviour you obvserve (ie, the elements resize individually first) is simply the browser resizing the elements itself (note, in the page you linked, the bricks have a relative width of `16%`), "Then a beat later" is when the throttled `resize` event kicks in to recalculate the bricks position. Using absolutely sized elements may help, or decrease the throttling on the `resize` event.

Comment: Isotope is the upgrade of Masonry. Both libraries/plugins are from the same developer (*[David DeSandro](http://stackoverflow.com/users/182183/desandro)*). The *problem* occurs because the resize event fires too fast/often, and since the plugins recalculate the new positions with javascript, a [*debounce*](http://unscriptable.com/2009/03/20/debouncing-javascript-methods/) is happening to control the madness..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### http://jsfiddle.net/UTB5C/3/

the result of masonry selected elements after resizing the window are a bit funny so i have added a resize event on the window to reload when window resized

```
$(function () {

    $('#wrapper').masonry({
        itemSelector: 'div',
        isResizable: true,
        gutterWidth: 5
    });
    $(window).on("resize", function () {
            $('#wrapper').masonry('reload')
    });

});
```